# Endeca - Number of max refinements more than 200 not displayed

Tags: atg, endeca, atg-dynamo, endeca-workbench

We have added a new facet under GuidedNavigation as a RefinementMenu.
The number of possible values for this facet/filter is around 1000 post Indexing. We have configured Max. refinements value as 9999 in Endeca workbench and published the changes.
When we try to display these values in ATG, we are getting only 200 values instead of 1000 values.

Comment: are you able to see all refinements in jspref?

Comment: Try setting 'showMore' to true.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved, the issue were as below

1. Publish project from Endeca was not working.
2. Max number of refinements to be configured as 9999 for both options - Max. Refinements and More Max. refinements.

If either is 200, it limits the returned results to 200.